# Why does this Android NDK code crash when run from a shared library?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am attempting to move some code from an Android NDK app into a shared library. Here's the code:

```
void *(*ATrace_beginSection) (const char* sectionName);

typedef void *(*fp_ATrace_beginSection) (const char* sectionName);

void doSomeStuff(){

  // Dynamically load the tracing functions
  void *lib = dlopen("libandroid.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL);

  if (lib != NULL) {

    // The following line causes a crash when called from a shared library
    ATrace_beginSection =
            reinterpret_cast<fp_ATrace_beginSection >(
                    dlsym(lib, "ATrace_beginSection"));
  }
}
```

The code works fine when I run from a standalone app, but when I try to put it inside a shared library I get a segmentation fault at the line starting with `ATrace_beginSection =`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Without the full crash report it hard to be certain, but I'm guessing there are undefined symbols?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that your library's ATrace_beginSection global data is colliding with libandroid.so's ATrace_beginSection function.
You call dlopen with RTLD_LOCAL.  But RTLD_LOCAL is not implemented until API level 23, as noted in
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html .

If the libandroid.so function ATrace_beginSection was assigned to instead of your data, that would crash with a SIGSEGV.
If renaming your library's ATrace_beginSection pointer stops the crash it would confirm that was the problem.